# Chat application image sending and receiving issue

Tags: php, chat, google-cloud-messaging, image-manipulation, image-resizing

I am making my Android based chat application using PHP language and trying to get image. But as we know gcm cannot give notification for more then 4kb. I am facing trouble to converting an image of big size on my server and get it notify by gcm to user end.

For example
(User 1)-send image of 300kb to (user 2)

(User-2) is unable to get this image

Reason (its more than 4kb) size.

So how to convert this image to less than 4kb and how can (user2) download it from my server?

As we all know gcm send a url to recever for eg. In whats app a receiver see thumb nail and a blur image ...but if we send image of 250 kb to somebody he will receive near about 50 kb ...so what is the in between process at server end and at gcm side.  Please help. I am not from IT background learning programming by other help.

Answer (score 0):

As you know GCM can carry payload of 4kb, you can send image link as a message and download image from the link directly on the device. You can also keep a `status flag` in message to facilitate client to distinguish between the `normal message` and `resource to be downloaded message`.

Whatsapp uses `XMPP protocol` and does not have limit of 4kb on message size. Hence it is feasible for whatsapp to send blurred images even if it exceeds the size. However GCM has the limitation. Hence to follow the limit, you need to compress the image using [PHP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). Since you need to ensure 4kb size for all images, try using very small sizes such as 16px x 16px or so. Such images will be blurred but can act as placeholder for actual image. Then you can download image from the link as mentioned above.

Comment: I am doing it;by encode image in base64 string format but the size of string is increasing above 4k;now what is alternate of reducing string below 4k;that is issue now.can you help in the same.

Comment: base64 only converts binary data into string. You need to compress the image first. Try [thumbnailimage](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php) function to compress the image. You can not specify the size in kbs, however try to compress image to lower resolutions such as 48px x 48px or so. Then convert it to base64. This shall reduce your image size.